# Create wrapper for multiple instances of an Event Handler

Tags: go, wrapper, channel, knative

I'm trying to deal with a problem (most probably a design one) regarding the usage of Channels and the proper handling of those.
I'm using Knative Eventing/Cloud Events to create and eventing pipeline.

I want to be able to handle different channels in order to receive events originating from different sources/methods.

In order to do so, I have the implementation that follows (code has been removed in order to be concise with detailing the issue).

I have a `file1.go` which defines a `EventHandler` struct, associated methods and a couple of exported methods (`CreatePreview()` and `SaveAndPublish()`) that are the "normal" behaviour of the app and that actually receives/deals with whatever value comes on the Channel:

```
type EventHandler struct {
  Channel chan string
}

func (ev *EventHandler) Handle(event cloudevents.Event) {
  if event.Data == nil {
    (...)
  }

  var data string
  if err := event.DataAs(&data); err != nil {
    (...)
  }

  ev.Channel <- data

  defer close(ev.Channel)
}

func (ev *EventHandler) Create(param *Element) (error) {
  (...) //Unimportant code
}

func (repo *Repository) CreatePreview(param1 string, param2 string, eventHandler *EventHandler) (*pb.PreviewResponse, error) {
  (...)
  err := eventHandler.Create(&document)
  (...)
  preview := <- eventHandler.Channel
  (...)
}

func (repo *Repository) SaveAndPublish(param1 string, param2 bool, eventHandler *EventHandler) (*pb.PublishResponse, error) {

  (...)
  err := eventHandler.Create(&documentToUpdate)
  (...)

  published := <- eventHandler.Channel
  (...)
  return repo.SomeOtherMethod(published.ID)
}
```

Now, on my `main.go` function, I have the "regular" start of a service, including a gRPC Listener, a HTTP Listener and handling of events. This is done via `cmux`. So here's a sample of the code (again, code simplified):

```
func HandlerWrapper(event cloudevents.Event) {
    //TODO: HOW DO I HANDLE THIS???
}

// This approach seems to cause issues since it's always the same instance
// var (
//  eventHandler = &rep.EventHandler{Channel: make(chan string)}
// )

func (service *RPCService) Start() (err error) {

  port, err := strconv.Atoi(os.Getenv("LISTEN_PORT"))
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
  }

  lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", fmt.Sprintf(":%d", port))
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
  }

  // Create multiplexer and listener types
  mux := cmux.New(lis)
  grpcLis := mux.Match(cmux.HTTP2())
  httpLis := mux.Match(cmux.HTTP1())

  // *************
  // gRPC
  // *************
  service.server = grpc.NewServer()
  reflection.Register(service.server)
  pb.RegisterStoryServiceServer(service.server, service)

  // *************
  // HTTP
  // *************

  // Declare new CloudEvents Receiver
  c, err := kncloudevents.NewDefaultClient(httpLis)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Failed to create client, ", err)
  }

  // *************
  // Start Listeners
  // *************

  // start gRPC server
  go func() {
    if err := service.server.Serve(grpcLis); err != nil {
      log.Fatalf("failed to gRPC serve: %s", err)
    }
  }()

  // start HTTP server
  go func() {
    // With this line bellow, I'd have to create a Received per eventHandler. Not cool
    // log.Fatal(c.StartReceiver(context.Background(), eventHandler.Handle))

    // Here we use a wrapper to deal with the event handling and have a single listener
    log.Fatal(c.StartReceiver(context.Background(), HandlerWrapper))
  }()

  if err := mux.Serve(); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("failed to Mux serve: %s", err)
  }

  return
}

//CreatePreview is used to save a preview for a story 
func (service *RPCService) CreatePreview(ctx context.Context, input *pb.PreviewRequest) (*pb.PreviewResponse, error){

  eventHandler := &rep.EventHandler{Channel: make(chan string)}

  story, err := service.repo.CreatePreview("param1", "param2", eventHandler)
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }

  // Return matching the `CreatePreviewResponse` message we created in our
  // protobuf definition.
  return &pb.PreviewResponse{Story: story}, nil
}

// SaveAndPublish is used to save a story and publish it, returning the story saved. 
func (service *RPCService) SaveAndPublish(ctx context.Context, input *pb.PublishRequest) (*pb.PublishResponse, error){

  eventHandler := &rep.EventHandler{Channel: make(chan string)}

  story, err := service.repo.SaveAndPublish("param1", true, eventHandler)

  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }

  // Return matching the `SaveAndPublishResponse` message we created in our
  // protobuf definition.
  return &pb.PublishResponse{Story: story}, nil
}
```

Now, I know that instead of having to instantiate a single, global `eventHandler`, in order to use the `eventHandler.Handle` method on `c.StartReceiver()` on `main.go` I can define a wrapper that would, maybe, contain a list of eventHandlers (the `HandlerWrapper()` method on `main.go`).

However, I do not know how I could identify which instance of an `EventHandler` is which and how to properly handle and route these operations, and that is my question:

How do I go about this case where I want to create a Wrapper (a single function to pass into `c.StartReceive()`) and then let it be handled by the correct instance of `Handle()`?

I hope the question is clear. I've been trying to get my head around this for a couple days already and can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you should be able to differentiate events by using the different sources/methods coming from that event. A quick look at the [event spec](https://github.com/cloudevents/spec/blob/master/spec.md#event) shows you could split into channels based on source, for example.

The main thing I see that isn't being utilized here is the context object. It seems you could glean the source from that context. This can be seen in their [hello world](https://knative.dev/docs/eventing/samples/helloworld/helloworld-go/) example (check out the receive function).

For your example:

```
// these are all the handlers for the different sources.
type EventHandlers map[string]CloudEventHandler

var _eventHandlerKey = "cloudEventHandlers"

func HandlerWrapper(ctx context.Context, event cloudevents.Event) {
    // Get event source from event context.
    src := event.Context.Source
    // Then get the appropriate handler for that source (attached to context).
    handler := ctx.Value(_eventHandlers).(Values)[src]
    // ex: src = "/foo" 
    handler.SendToChannel(event)
}

func main() {
    eventHandlers := make(map[string]CloudEventHandler)
    // create all the channels we need, add it to the context.
    for _, source := range sourceTypes { // foo bar baz
        handler := NewHandler(source)
        eventHandlers[source] = handler
    }

  // start HTTP server
  go func() {
    // Add the handlers to the context.
    context := context.WithValue(context.Background(), _eventHandlerKey, eventHandlers)
    log.Fatal(c.StartReceiver(context.Background(), HandlerWrapper))
  }
}()
```

If there are say 3 different sources to be supported, you can use the [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to instantiate those different channels and an interface that all of those implement.

```
// CloudEventHandler Handles sending cloud events to the proper channel for processing.
type CloudEventHandler interface {
    SendToChannel(cloudEvents.Event)
}

type fooHandler struct {channel chan string}
type barHandler struct {channel chan int}
type bazHandler struct {channel chan bool}

func NewHandler(source string) CloudEventHandler {
    switch source {
    case "/foo":
        return &fooHandler{channel: make(chan string, 2)} // buffered channel
    case "/bar":
        return &barHandler{channel: make(chan int, 2)}
    case "/baz":
        return &bazHandler{channel: make(chan bool, 2)}
    }
}

func (fh *fooHandler) SendToChannel(event CloudEvents.Event) {
    var data string
    if err := event.DataAs(&data); err != nil {
        // (...)
    }

    go func() {
        fh.channel <- data
    }()
}

func (bh *barHandler) SendToChannel(event CloudEvents.Event) {
    var data int
    if err := event.DataAs(&data); err != nil {
        // (...)
    }

    go func() {
        bh.channel <- data
    }()
}
```